# Generic type function to operate on different types of input objects

Tags: vb.net

I have lists such as (these are just made up examples):

```
Dim peopleContactedToday as list (of People) =  getPeople() 
Dim companiesContactedToday as list (of Company) = getCompanies()
```

Now suppose `People` class and `Company` class both has a property `DateContacted`.  I want to create a generic function that takes any of the arrays and set `DateContacted`.

I tried this, but doesn't compile because of course compiler doesn't know if T has a property `DateContacted`.

```
Function SetData(Of T)(InputArr As List(Of T)) As List(Of T)
     For Each item In InputArr
         item.DataContacted = Now().Date
     Next
     return InputArr
End Function
```

How to write generic functions in VB.net to operate on properties that exists in all of them.  I can see that I can have a root class with `DateContacted` property and inherit both `Person` and `Company` from it. Then instead of using T in above method I can use that interface, but that is not really generic function and suppose these two classes in the example are generated by Entity Framework (where I can't put an parent interface).

Comment: You don´t need any generic here. Just create an Interface, e.g. `IContactable` and put the `DateContacted` into the interface. Now let both your classes `People` and `Company` implement this interface. Change your function to a sub like `Sub SetData(InputArr As IEnumerable(Of IContactable))`. No need to return anything sinced you directly manipualting the objects in the list/enumerable.

Comment: Thanks.  But these classes are generated by Entity Framework and maps to DB tables. So I don't want to alter them b/c next time I update EF model, the updates may be gone.

Comment: That´s also no problem. Just create `Partial` classes for `People` and `Company` in two different `.vb` files. Let them implement the interface there. EF won´t overwrite them. I´ve done sth similar last week so I know it works.

Comment: As @AlexB. says, you should make use of partial classes.  This is pretty much exactly what they exist for.  This is basically the same situation as the auto-generated designer code for a Windows Form being in one partial class in one code file and the user code in another.